# Why does React think I'm not calling `useState` "inside the body of a function component"?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app in Typescript where I'm trying to use the `useState` hook in one section and running into trouble. I've reduced the code to the following minimal example:

`projects-loader.tsx`:

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import MoreProjectsTable from "./components/MoreProjectsTable";

export const projects = (): void => {
  const moreProjectsRootEl = document.getElementById(
    "react-more-projects-table-root"
  );
  render(<MoreProjectsTable/>, moreProjectsRootEl);
};

export default projects;
```

`MoreProjectsTable.tsx`:

```js
import React, { ReactElement, useState } from "react";
import MoreProjectsRow from "./MoreProjectsRow";

const MoreProjectsTable = (): ReactElement<HTMLElement> => {
  useState();
  return (<div/>);
};

export default MoreProjectsTable;
```

But when I call `projects()` it fails with the error "Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component."

I understand from research that there are three common reasons for this error:

1. Violating the Rules Of Hooks
2. Mismatching versions of React and React-DOM
3. Multiple copies of React in the same app

Regarding #1, I don't see where I'm violating the Rules Of Hooks--it looks to me like I'm calling `useState` from the top-level of a function component, all right.

Regarding #2, I verified that React and React-DOM are both v16.8.1.

Regarding #3, I verified via the method described on [this page](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/two-weird-tricks-that-fix-react-7cf9bbdef375) that that is not the case.

Can anyone suggest anything else I might try? I'm very new to React so no suggestion is too obvious.

Comment: I don't know the answer but my hunch is that maybe the types aren't compatible. Consider trying `const MoreProjectsTable: React.FunctionComponent = () => {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About one minute after I posted this question, a co-worker figured it out. This app is running on a Web page and, without noticing it, I was loading the top-level script itself from two different places. A variation on scenario #3 then, apparently.